# Can “during the last few months” be used with present perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Here are the sentences:

> We **haven’t eaten** at that restaurant *during the last few months.*
>
> We **didn’t eat** at that restaurant *during the last few months*.

I think ***during*** implies the duration has ended, hence the past tense not present perfect.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

During the last few months means until now, so let's say from August until today. Present perfect would be appropriate. To me "in the last few months" sounds better though. If you want to use past simple you'd have to specify a past period when you didn't eat at the restaurant, like "we didn't eat at the restaurant in September.